# passenger-memory-stats works, passenger-config validate-install works fine, passenger-status says not running?

Tags: apache, passenger, centos7

Centos 7 server. Passenger installed with gem

As per title:

```
$ passenger-config validate-install
  "Everything looks good :-)"

$ passenger-memory-stats
  All the details of apache and passenger running.
```

I can go to the site and it works fine.

passenger-status output says "ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running..."

I haven't customized any directories or done anything unusual up to this point that I'm aware of but passenger-status is apparently looking in the wrong place.

Suggestions on how to fix please?

Thanks

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Ah sorry thought I answered this before - I never managed to properly resolve the problem. Instead I uninstalled then reinstalled using yum instead of gem.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's an issue with either an updated version of nginx or passenger. Because on one box it works perfectly, follow the same steps from 6 months ago, it doesn't work.

Comment: I wasn't/am not using nginx. Suspect it was a permissions problem when installed through gem but don't know for certain, gave up debugging and reinstalled with yum. Sorry can't help more.